# swiftEntryKit custom pop up nib not loading data

Tags: ios, swift, nib, pass-data

I have a custom popup from a nib using [swiftEntryKit](https://github.com/huri000/SwiftEntryKit) which displays data from the user the currentUser has clicked on.

1. I have a nib file called `UserRequestView`
2. and a UIView class called `UserRequestView`
3. I also have another UIView class called `UserRequestPreviewView` which is the nibs custom class and sets up all of the data on the nib file

when the currentUser selects another user from a collectionView inside of `NewHomeViewController` the currentUser is presented with a popup screen asking whether to send a friend request. To present the popup view I use this:

```
`SwiftEntryKit.display(entry: UserRequestView(), using: popupAttributes)`
```

and to load data into the nib:

```
if let popupView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("UserRequestView", owner: self, options: nil)!.first as? UserRequestPreviewView {               
    popupView.currentUser = self.currentUser
    popupView.user = self.users[self.theUserIndex]
}
```

When running the project and clicking on to a user, the popup is displayed fine and the data has loaded into the nib, However, the images and text on the nib have not changed.

for more context, here is the UserRequestView class:

```
class UserRequestView: UIView {

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}

init() {
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    setup()
}
private func setup() {
    fromNib()

}

}
```

the method `fromNib` is an extension of UIView:

```
extension UIView {

@discardableResult
func fromNib<T : UIView>() -> T? {
    guard let contentView = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).loadNibNamed(type(of: self).className, owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? T else {
        return nil
    }

    addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.fillSuperview()
    return contentView
}
}
```

and the class I use to setup the nib to display the data:

```
class UserRequestPreviewView: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var userProfileImage: roundedImage!
@IBOutlet weak var userFirstLastName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var usersBirthday: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var friendsOptionBtn: UIButton!

var currentUser: User!
var user: User! {
    didSet {
        if currentUser != nil {
            print("the current user = \(currentUser.firstName)")
            print("this user = \(user.firstName)")
            setUp()
        }
    }
}
var cache = SAMCache.shared()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    layer.applySketchShadow()
    layer.cornerRadius = 20
    layer.masksToBounds = false

    friendsOptionBtn.layer.cornerRadius = friendsOptionBtn.bounds.height / 2.0
    friendsOptionBtn.layer.masksToBounds = true

    userProfileImage.layer.cornerRadius = userProfileImage.bounds.height / 2.0
    userProfileImage.layer.masksToBounds = true

    friendsOptionBtn.isEnabled = true

}

 func setUp(){

    print("got to set up")

     let profileImageKey = "\(user.uid)-profileImage"
     if let image = cache?.object(forKey: profileImageKey) as? UIImage{

        self.userProfileImage.image = image
        print("setting image 1")

     }else{
         user.downloadProfilePicture { [weak self] (image, error) in
             if let image = image {
                 self?.userProfileImage.image = image
                print("setting image 2")
                 self?.cache?.setObject(image, forKey: profileImageKey)
             }else if error != nil {
                print(error)
             }
        }
    }

     userFirstLastName.text = "\(user.firstName) \(user.lastName)"
     usersBirthday.text = "\(user.birthday)"
}
}
```

I know that the currentUser and user have been set into the nib because the print statements show in the console

"got to set up" prints and so does "setting image 1"

I don't understand why the images and text are not displaying in the nib. Does anyone have a solution? thanks.

Comment: It might be helpful to name your nib something slightly more obviously different from the UIView. maybe 'UserRequestViewNib'.

Comment: Also what is the purpose of the `userRequestView : UIView`? it seems un-used.

Comment: it is used by swiftEntryKit in: `SwiftEntryKit.display(entry: UserRequestView(), using: popupAttributes)`

Comment: @Wez I think the problem has something to do with fromNib method

Comment: You need to check your class name capitalisation `UserRequestView()` and `userRequestView()` are different classes.

Comment: oh sorry these are the same, just a typo when placing into stack overflow

Comment: Have you tried `SwiftEntryKit.display(entry: UserRequestPreviewView(), using: popupAttributes)` ?

Comment: Yes. This doesn't display the popup view. I think it is because to display the view using swiftEntryKit I need the fromNib() method which adds the nib as a subView